# How to check key of prop object from array in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

With the following code I can check the type of the incoming props, however how do I check the internals of each object inside of the array assets?

```
AssetsTable.propTypes = {
    assets: PropTypes.array.isRequired
}
```

Say for example if I wanted to check `assets[0].id: PropTypes.string.isRequired`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do something like

```
React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
  React.PropTypes.shape({
    id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  })
).isRequired
```

see [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for more information

Comment: Nice! That was it thanks! I didn't see that kinda of nested example in the docs for checking an object in the Array.